# Unknown system bitsize for int, how to create mask

Tags: c, bit, mask, portability

I would like to create a mask for the MSB only, however the width of the int on the operating system is suppose to be unknown, so you cannot assume 32 bits.

see the following

```
    // THE FOLLOWING FAILS BECAUSE OF SYSTEM IMPLEMENTING A LOGICAL 
    // RIGHT SHIFT
    // Idea is 
    //     1. 0 inverted = all 1's
    //     2. Arithmetic shift right
    //     3. Then invert again to preseve MSB '1'
    const int unsigned mask = ~(~0>>1); // FAIL, because of logic shift
```

### Assuming 16 bit system

1. ~0 give FFFF
2. ~0>>1 give 7FFF
3. ~(~0 >> 1) give 8000

Comment: Are you  looking for the MSBit of `int` or `unsigned`?  (They do not have to be the same.) 
 Looking for an `int` or `unsigned` mask?

Comment: @chux. If system has int that is 8,16,32 or 64 bits then I want the code to get msb. Mikecat has the answer

Comment: Wes Taylor-Rendal, Mikecat answer provide the MSBit of an unsigned which, rarely, differs from your int goal.  Further that answer does not work for 8-bit and maybe not 16-bit.

Answer (score 4):

You should add an `u` suffix to make what is shifted unsigned so that logical right shift is performed instead of arithmetic one.

```
const int unsigned mask = ~(~0u>>1);
```

Comment: Maybe "postfix"?

Comment: Relies on the _very common_ implementation detail that `INT_MAX*2 + 1 == UINT_MAX`.  Something not required by C, but is ubiquitous.

Comment: This fixed the problem. I guess the type casting needs to take place on the RHS of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can just *left* shift the (unsigned) value `1` by the number of bits in the type minus 1 (i.e. for a 32-bit type, the MSB will be `1 << 31`). To get the number of bits, use a combination of the `sizeof` operator and the `CHAR_BIT` constant ([defined in `<limits.h>`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/)):

```c
const unsigned int MSB = 1u << (sizeof(unsigned int) * CHAR_BIT - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`INT_MAX` is the `int` bit pattern of `0111...1111` (of some width)<sup>*</sup> for all implementations.

To form `1000...0000`, invert those bits.

```
~INT_MAX
```

The above treads on *undefined beahvior* (UB).
Better to looks to unsigned or wider types.

```
unsigned mask = ~(unsigned) INT_MAX;
```

On rare machines, `INT_MAX == UINT_MAX`, so on those, look to wider types:

```
long long = ~(long long) INT_MAX;
```

On rarer machines (unheard of), `INT_MAX == LONG_MAX` is *also* true, then we are out of luck.

---

Pedantic: Rare machines use padding on `int/unsigned`, so best to drive code with `(U)INT_MAX` than `sizeof`.

---

<sup>*</sup> *Maybe* some padding bits too - very rare.

Comment: Is this using precompiler?

Comment: @WesTaylor-Rendal    depends on tool set, but likely is.  Why is this a concern?